# Self Intersection mod 2 of Central curve on Möbius band

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, intersection-theory

I need to proof that the self intersection mod 2 of the central curve in a Möbius band, i.e., $I_2(X,X)=1$.

What I think is that we can use the homotopy invariance of the intersection no. and deform $X$ to get $X'$ which transversally intersects $X$.

But I am not exactly sure how it will help us to prove what is desired .

Kindly help!!

thanks & regards in advance

Comment: How are you "drawing" the Möbius band?

Comment: It can be thought of as ends of a rectangular strip joined with a twist. @TedShifrin

Comment: Let's be more specific. Think of it as the unit square,  $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, with $(0,t)$ identified with $(1,1-t)$. Where are $X$ and $X'$ in this picture?

Comment: Ohkay .. so, X is exactly the central line X' being the deformation I am not sure about it, possibly it may not intersect X it could be anywhere I guess @TedShifrin

Comment: How can it not intersect $X$ anywhere? Remember that it has to be a closed loop on the Möbius strip. What does that mean happens in your picture?

Comment: What if we deform X to shift it towards the edge of the square ? Where am i wrong @TedShifrin?

Comment: Don't forget what makes your picture of the Möbius strip different from a picture of a cylinder.

Comment: The orientation of one edge is different from other but I am not aware of the consequences can u suggest something to read so that it helps me @Tedshifrin?

Comment: Think about where your $X'$ intersects the segments $x=0$ and $x=1$ if we've identified $(0,t)$ with $(1,1-t)$.

Comment: i think i get it, if we try to deform X then we  will just get a slight rotation of X about the centre of X resulting in the intersection at the centre of the square precisely at x=1/2. Am I correct ? @TedShifrin

Comment: More generally, take the graph of any smooth function on $[0,1]$ with appropriate conditions at $0$ and $1$.

Comment: What appropriate conditions , can you explain a bit more briefly? @TedShifrin??

Comment: First, you should have arrived at $f(1) = 1 - f(0) \ne 1/2$, so that $f(0)-1/2$ and $f(1)-1/2$ have opposite signs. Next, you need all the derivatives to satisfy $f^{(k)}(0)=-f^{(k)}(1)$  so that $X'$ will be a smooth submanifold.  (Probably you shouldn't worry about this now.)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. U actually helped me solve the problem :) @TedShifrin